# How to compare HEAD to another branch using GitLens in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, compare, diff

Finding the command to compare my current working changes with another branch took me a long time; posting this question to save others time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using the "GitLens: Compare Head with..." command documented here: https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/tree/master/#and-more-

From here in the sidebar you can view your committed and uncommitted changes compared against a branch of your choosing.